# Motional EMF with a rod in a closed loop

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, voltage, induction

Let me preface this by saying that while this is a problem which came from my college physics class, it was not a graded assignment, it was optional study material (and you can see from the photo I've already completed it). So I am not just looking for somebody to do my homework for me.

[image]

I am very confused about the answer to part i of this problem. It seems to me that it should not need to be multiplied by two.

If we get rid of the conducting loop, leaving just the rod moving through the magnetic field, it seems E=BLv. And if I understand motional EMF correctly, E=BLv is still true once you place the rod on this conducting loop.

If this is true, then why is the current through the rod multiplied by two? If the loop was only closed at one end, you'd simply say I=V/R. And if the loop has zero resistance, why does having it closed at both ends instead of just one end change the current across AB? This seems to go against everything I intuitively know about how electricity behaves.

Comment: Aren't there two paths now for the current to flow?

Comment: I think that you have been asked to find the change in magnetic flux in a time $\Delta t$.